# Obtain Decision Boundary for SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

In the following example:
     http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html

I would like to obtain the coefficients of the (line) decision boundary shown in the picture.
A call to

```
clf.coef_
```

returns

```
[[-0.2539717  -0.83806387]]
```

which, if I am not mistaken, represents the line of equation

```
y = -0.83806387 * x - 0.2539717
```

However, the above line is not the decision boundary obtained in the example, so what exactly is coef_ and how can I obtain the equation of the linear decision boundary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the equation for the line of the decision boundary of a linear model you need to get both the `coef_` and `intercept_`. Also note that since you are using a SVC there will be multiple decision boundaries involved.

The line equation can be constructed as:

`y = w0 + w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + ...`

Where `w0` is obtained from `intercept_`, `w1` onwards are found in `coef_`, and `x1` and onwards are your features.

For example, this code shows you how to print out the equations for each of your decision boundaries.

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

clf = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 1], [6, 2]])
y = np.array(["A", "B", "A", "C"])

clf.fit(X, y)

for (intercept, coef) in zip(clf.intercept_, clf.coef_):
    s = "y = {0:.3f}".format(intercept)
    for (i, c) in enumerate(coef):
        s += " + {0:.3f} * x{1}".format(c, i)

    print(s)
```

In this example, the lines are determined to be:

```
y = 2.800 + -0.200 * x0 + -0.800 * x1
y = 7.000 + -1.000 * x0 + -1.000 * x1
y = 1.154 + -0.462 * x0 + 0.308 * x1
```

Source: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

Comment: Tx for your explanation ! Yes, that helps. For a test with an example see my answer..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw linear plot i.e. y = ax + b then you can use below chunk of code

```
tmp = clf.coef_[0]
a = - tmp[0] / tmp[1]

b = - (clf.intercept_[0]) / tmp[1]

xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1])
yy = a * xx + b
plt.plot(xx, yy)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps. For a test with an example see my answer.

Comment: can someone explain why a = - tmp[0] / tmp[1] and b = - (clf.intercept_[0]) / tmp[1]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Prem and @Christopher Wells - this was realy helpful. I combined both answers because in Prem's code is no y_target included (--> see Christopher's answer), which works fine for y_target=0.

As an example I used the [logRegression tutorial from scikitLearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-iris-logistic-py). I inserted the following code:

```
mf = logreg.intercept_.shape[0];
xm = np.r_[np.min(X),np.max(X)]
yf = logreg.classes_.copy()
xm = np.r_[np.min(X),np.max(X)]

for jf in np.arange(mf):
    tmp = logreg.coef_[jf]
    a = - tmp[0] / tmp[1]; 
    b = - (logreg.intercept_[jf]-yf[jf]) / tmp[1]
    yy = a * xm + b
    plt.plot(xm, yy, label='Coeff ='+str(jf))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is perfect for y_target=0 (see graphic in the skLearn example). But what is with the other 2 straight lines ? Has anything more to be considerd ?
[image: Examlpe from scikitLearn: LogisticRegression]